# Doctrine 2 Collection not connected or filled

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine setup where i cant use the many side of collections.

The objects used:
User.php:

```
class User extends \App\Entity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="users")
    */
    private $company;

    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }
    public function setCompany($company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
}
```

Company.php:

```
class Company extends \App\Entity
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $users;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

When i create the relation seems to be working. Get no errors. Then i tried the following:

```
$company = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Company')->findOneByName("Walmart");
$user = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneByName("Niek");
$user->setCompany($company);

$company2 = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Company')->findOneByName("Ford");
$user2 = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneByName("Henk");
$company2->getUsers()->add($user2);
$this->em->flush();
```

When i inspect the database for the first user the company is set. Relation is there. The seconds does not persists. and when i do this:

```
print_r(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($company->getUsers(),$doctrineDepth));
print_r(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($company->getUsers2(),$doctrineDepth));
```

i get 2 empty arrays.

So it seems that the array isnt connected. It only behaves like this on OneToMany ore ManyToOne relationships. Got one ManyToMany and that one works perfect in the same project

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to set both sides of the relationship with a one-to-many or a many-to-one relationship:

```
$company2 = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Company')->findOneByName("Ford");
$user2 = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneByName("Henk");
$company2->getUsers()->add($user2);
$user2->setCompany($company2);
$this->em->flush();
```

The reason your many-to-many works is because you don't need to set both sides of the relationship.

Comment: That would indeeed save the company. But it doesnt solve the issue that my $company->getUsers() keeps being empty. And that would defeat the purpose of a bidirectional relation.

Comment: Try removing your `extends \App\Entity` as Doctrine will try and create a proxy class that extends your entity and implements `\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy` in order to load the relations. PHP does not support multiple inheritance. Alternatively craft your query to ensure it includes all the relationships you try and fetch.

Comment: Proxy class does not get generated? All the settings are there. And there was one generated file. Deleted it so it could be regenerated. But nothing happens.